# Tensorflow on GPU WIndows 11

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu

I have Windows 11, nVidia GTX 1650 Ti and I am trying to make Tensorflow work on the GPU. And one absolute condition: I don't want to even think about Linux. It has to work on Windows. Currently on Python 3.11.2, Tensorflow 2.13.1

I tried official nVidia guide to install cuda and cudnn, some articles from medium.com and still nothing. I switched from PyCharm to Visual studio Code. Nothing. Installing through conda. Nothing. I tried newest cuda and cudnn versions, cuda 11.8 with cudnn 8.6.0 or with cudnn 8.9.7 and still nothing. Tensorflow just can't see my GPU. And yes, nVidia Game drivers are updated. I have no other ideas except linux, but i would rather jump from the window than use linux. I'm a mathematician, not IT specialist, so please give me step-by-step solution. Thanks in advance

```
import sys
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

print(f"Tensor Flow Version: {tf.__version__}")
print(f"Keras Version: {keras.__version__}")
print()
print(f"Python {sys.version}")
gpu = len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))>0
print("GPU is", "available" if gpu else "NOT AVAILABLE")
```

[result of code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywn6d.png)

Comment: Well you are  out of luck, because to use TensorFlow GPU on Windows you have to use WSL, read the note at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native , unless you mean something else about not using Linux (WSL is Linux actually).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to downgrade your TF version to 2.10 or lesser to work on native-Windows (not recommended though)

> GPU support on native-Windows is only available for 2.10 or earlier versions, starting in TF 2.11, CUDA build is not supported for Windows. The correct supported CUDA and cuDNN version for Tensorflow 2.10 are CUDA 11.2 and cuDNN 8.1 as mentioned in this tested build config

link : https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/issues-installing-tensorflow-on-windows-11-with-nvidia-2060/19663

> Caution: TensorFlow 2.10 was the last TensorFlow release that supported GPU on native-Windows. Starting with TensorFlow 2.11, you will need to install TensorFlow in WSL2, or install tensorflow or tensorflow-cpu and, optionally, try the TensorFlow-DirectML-Plugin

link: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native

Comment: So how do I install DirectML plugin? I tried "pip install tensorflow-directml-plugin", but Visual Studio Code found no versions available

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-directml-plugin/#description.. It only supports till python 3.10 your python is 3.11. You have to use python 3.10.

Comment: I downgraded Python to 3.10.11 and now pip does not work:

"pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip install tensorflow-cpu
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException"

And people say math is complicated...

Comment: It finally works! If anyone happens to have the same problem, here's what i did: I left Python 3.10 installed and reinstalled 3.11. Suddenly, it could install tensorflow-cpu and the plugin. I switch interpreter to 3.10 and finally the GPU is available. Thank you all